# How to build an extra package in Yocto project after the image is built

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build my Yocto project recently, and I am going to build a custom package automatically after the image is built and copy the package to the deploy folder. I have finished the .bb file, and I can bitbake the package after the image   built manually, and it works. But I want to just run "bitbake image", to bitbake both the image and the custom package, how can I do it?

Comment: You should append the name of the recipe to image recipe name. Something like `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` in your image recipe.

Answer (score 0):

IMAGE_INSTALL specifies the packages to install in your image,  so its better to append your recipe name to this.

or

One more easier way is to add your recipe name to  IMAGE_INSTALL_append. you can add this in conf/local.file as below.

IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " your_recipe"

Comment: Yes, IMAGE_INSTALL can make my recipe be built and installed, but I plan to copy the binary of my recipe to the deploy folder, rather than installed to the image's rootfs. Thus it can cause image's recipe do_roofts error.

Comment: DEPLOY_DIR this variable points to the build/tmp/deploy folder, try this variable in your do_install() to copy your binary into this folder, I guess this will work !!